# Nat - Virtual Server Configuration

Tags: configuration, router, nat

I'm trying to make my server accessible from the net.

I have problem with configuration of NAT in the router. I don't know what I'm suppose to write in 'Remote Host'. Should I put the Static ip(ISP) there or the dynamic adress of the host that will connect to my server or nothing ?
[nat configuration image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2jyL.png)

local adress of the server : 192.168.1.11

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specifics of your router, but I'm guessing this field will limit incoming connections to only be allowed from a specific remote IP. So should be left empty in your case as it already is.